# Is there a way to make an enum available all over the meanjs stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, meanjs

I'm experimenting with the meanjs stack and I'm trying to declare an an enum like array in a single place and make it available everywhere in the project from Mongo all the way up to Angular. What would be an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Yes, you should be able to define a variable in one place and have node pass it to the required modules.

Comment: If it is not like a series of constants I would prefer to use services and $resource...

Comment: ... in core module (I forget to add this.)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have come up with.

Since the definition has to be available for both client and server I have created a globals  folder that can be accesed by the client code.

'myapp/public/globals/types.js'

```
'use strict';

(function (exports){

exports.PlaceTypes = ['restaurant', 'house', 'park'];

})(typeof exports === 'undefined' ? this[ApplicationConfiguration.applicationModuleName] = {} : exports);
```

In order to make it accesible I had to edit the 'myapp/config/env/all.js' adding the 'public/globals/*' before the modules line

```
...
    js: [
            'public/config.js',
            'public/application.js',
            'public/globals/*',
            'public/modules/*/*.js',
            'public/modules/*/*[!tests]*/*.js'
        ],
...
```

In the model I can just import it.

'myapp/app/models/place.server.model.js'

```
var PlaceTypes = require('../../public/globals/types').PlaceTypes;

/**
 * Place Schema
 */
var PlaceSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        enum: PlaceTypes,
        required: 'Please fill Place name',
        trim: true
    }
});
```

Now PlaceTypes is available every everywhere in the stack and is only defined once.